# How can I create model instance via Serializer without creating models from nested serialziers?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have model with many links into it:

```
class Travel(BaseAbstractModel):

    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag,
        related_name='travels',
        )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        'users.TravelUser',
        related_name='travel_owner'
        )
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        Payment,
        related_name='travels',
        )
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        Country,
        related_name='travels,
        )
    ........
```

Many of these models have only two fields with unique name and image. 
I create serializer for each of these models and put them in `TravelSerializer`

```
class TravelBaseSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):

    owner = UserSerializer(required=False)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    payment = PaymentSerializer()
    country = CountrySerializer()
```

Based on docs I override `create()` and `update`.
The problem is, when I sent JSON data, Django create each model from nested serializers. But I want to create only `Travel` instance. Also I want receive and respond serialized object not only `pk` field.

**UPDATE**
I solved this problem, put code in the answer. Now I can receive and respond with Serializer data without creating object. 
But I think the DRF provides more elegant approach then I do. It is my first project with DRF, maybe I miss something and there's an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decide override `to_internal_value()` put it in custom serailizer and inherit all nested serializers from it:

```
class NestedRelatedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
           pk = data['pk']
        except (TypeError, KeyError):
        # parse pk from request JSON
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'_error': 'object must provide pk!'})
        return pk
```

Get all `pk` from it and save in `create` and `updated` methods:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # If don't get instance from db, m2m field won't update immediately
        # I don't understand why
        instance = Travel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
        instance.payment_id = validated_data.get('payment', instance.payment_id)
        instance.country_id = validated_data.get('country', instance.country_id)
        # update m2m links
        instance.tags.clear()
        instance.tags.add(*validated_data.get('tags'))
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure I understand what you want to do, but could setting `read_only_fields` is the `Meta` class be what you need ?

```
class TravelBaseSerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):

    owner = UserSerializer(required=False)
    tags = TagSerializer(many=True)
    payment = PaymentSerializer()
    country = CountrySerializer()  

    class Meta:
        read_only_fields = ('tags',)
```

See [this section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) in the docs.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it in the first thing. Problem with `read_only_fields`, these fields do not pass to `validated_data`

Comment: OK so what I think you want is this: you want that when your serializer is used for reading puproses, it serializes all the related fields, and when used for writing puproses it tries to validate the related fields but not save them. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes, but I need this data in `validated_data`, because I need to fill all link fields in created `Travel` model. I solve it, like you can see in my answer. But I start this bounty, because, I want to find some best practice, for purposes like this. Now I think, DRF just not allow use nested serializers for purposes like that, by default

Comment: Again I'm not sure I understand exactly, you do not want the tags to be saved because they already exist and you only want the user to refer to existing tags using a primary key ?
If so, you may want to take a look at `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield.

Comment: I note all of this in question and my answer below, I look at PKRelatedField, but problem was with `to_representation` of this field, I want work with serializer as usual, all my fk and m2m fields should represented by JSON object, not only pk.

Comment: OK then I don't see any standard way to do it, I widh you good luck !

Comment: I found solution, just override `to_internal_value()`